# Is there a way to autodirect a predefined user query to a specific URL?

Tags: redirect, solr, e-commerce

An ecommerce search best practice, baymard research below, is to redirect a user query for a product type/category (e.g. mens shirts, mobile computer) to the corresponding category landing page and bypass the search results page?

I've searched Solr documentation and don't see this ability though I know it's offered in some ecommerce search engines.

https://baymard.com/blog/autodirect-searches-matching-category-scopes

Endeca keyword redirect
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E70265_01/platform.11-3/EndecaPlatDevStudioHelp/html/cds_about_keyword_redirects.xmlconcept_19F0C5098A1C4647824C8783817F0593.html

Comment: Solr won't be able to issue a redirect to your end client - it doesn't talk directly to Solr in most cases (.. and it wouldn't be able to cause a redirect anyway, so that would have to be implemented in your client).. That would have to be logic in your middleware, for example by sending the query to a separate core that contains query -> redirect lookups.